# Discriminate between CHLD sub shells in trap function

Tags: bash, shell-script, trap

I have this bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -m          # allow for job control
EXIT_CODE=0     # exit code of overall script

function foo() {
   echo "CHLD pid is $!"   # doesn't seem to be the expected pid
   echo "CHLD exit code is $?"  #exit code seems to pertain to some other process
   if [[ $? > 0 ]]; then
      echo "at least one test failed"
      EXIT_CODE=1
   fi
}

trap 'foo' CHLD

DIRN=$(dirname "$0")

commands=(
    "echo 'foo'; exit 1;"
    "echo 'bar'; exit 0;"
    "echo 'baz'; exit 2;"
)

clen=`expr "${#commands[@]}" - 1` # get length of commands - 1

for i in `seq 0 "$clen"`; do
    (echo "${commands[$i]}" | bash) &   # run the command via bash in subshell
    echo "$i ith command has been issued as a background job"
done

# wait for all to finish
wait

echo "EXIT_CODE => $EXIT_CODE"
exit "$EXIT_CODE"
```

Multiple subshells exit, and fire the foo function upon exit. I would have only expected 3 CHLD events captured by the foo function, but there are at least 6.

How can I discriminate between the `CHLD` events that appear in the `foo` function?

For example, here is the output of the above script:

```
CHLD exit code is 0
CHLD exit code is 0
CHLD exit code is 0
0 ith command has been issued as a background job
1 ith command has been issued as a background job
2 ith command has been issued as a background job
bar
baz
foo
CHLD exit code is 0
CHLD exit code is 0
CHLD exit code is 0
EXIT_CODE => 0
```

As you can see, there are 6 `CHLD` events; but I really only care about 3. Furthermore, I should be seeing 1,0,2 as exit codes, not 0,0,0.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to id which subshell is exiting in the foo function?
2. Why am I seeing 0 for the exit code, when it should be 1, or 2?

Comment: The extra CHLD events are from the various (unnecessary) subshells you used, `$(dirname ...)`, `\`expr ...\``,`\`seq ...\``, and I don't think `$!` will contain the exit status of backgrounded processes.

Comment: @muru IRL I am not using echo, instead I am using something that actually might want to run as background process :)

Comment: OK... I didn't say anything about `echo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why the `$?` and `$!` values in the `foo` function don't pertain to the `CHLD` in question, but the following fixes seem to get around the problem, by using `jobs -p` inside the `foo` function, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -m          # allow for job control
EXIT_CODE=0     # exit code of overall script

function foo() {
    for job in `jobs -p`; do
        echo "PID => ${job}"
        if ! wait ${job} ; then
            echo "At least one test failed with exit code => $?" ;
            EXIT_CODE=1;
        fi
    done
}

trap 'foo' CHLD

DIRN=$(dirname "$0")

commands=(
    "{ echo 'foo' && exit 4; }"
    "{ echo 'bar' && exit 3; }"
    "{ echo 'baz' && exit 5; }"
)

clen=`expr "${#commands[@]}" - 1` # get length of commands - 1

for i in `seq 0 "$clen"`; do
    (echo "${commands[$i]}" | bash) &   # run the command via bash in subshell
    echo "$i ith command has been issued as a background job"
done

wait       # wait for all to finish

echo "EXIT_CODE => $EXIT_CODE"
exit "$EXIT_CODE"
```

Comment: I heard from someone that jobs -p / wait <pid> does not work for subshells that have already finished, but in my experience it does. Maybe this depends on bash version.

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/